# Unix: Swapping Values Between XML Tags In a File

Tags: xml, unix, tags, swap

Using Unix command line how do I do the following? I am on Solaris 10 OS

```
From:

<Parent>
 <From>abc</From>
 <To>xyz</To>
</Parent>

to:

<Parent>
 <From>xyz</From>
 <To>abc</To>
</Parent>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use awk or sed you could use xsltproc, which should be available on Solaris (the package is called libxslt):

transform.xsl:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Parent">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="To"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="From"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

command line:

`xsltproc transform.xsl myfile.xml`

The above XSLT stylesheet uses an "identity transform" (the first template copies everything one-to-one) and adds a special rule for the Parent element. If your XML contains only the simple structure above, you could omit the first xsl:template.